# Ubuntu has been installed but computer still boots into windows

Tags: boot

Sorry if this is a stupid query, but I spent ages getting the Samsung NP905S3G to boot from usb and eventually got it to work. Wanted to try a dual-boot alongside windows 8 first and the install seemed to work but I now can't figure out how to boot the laptop in ubuntu without the usb. It keeps starting in windows no matter how I configure the BIOS. Any help welcome. Thanks

Edited to explain further :
I think Ubuntu has installed successfully. My problem now is getting it to boot.

Comment: It is almost always an option in your BIOS under boot or EFI or secure boot options. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi , first answer, troubleshooting section.

Comment: The use of large font and bold do not help in any way. We understand your computer boots directly to windows. Did you read the troubleshooting section in the link I gave you ? This is a bios / efi issue as ubuntu runs fine when booting from usb.

Comment: The use of large font wasn't intentional.

Comment: I did read the troubleshooting section, but I am not finding any GRUB menu or other option to boot from ubuntu anywhere in the BIOS - it only has Windows. I am going to take another look tonight.

Answer (score -2):

You need to install Grub on your boot partition to make your computer a dual boot, open Ubuntu from the installation disk and go to terminal and input:

> sudo fdisk -l

To learn which partition is the boot loader, in this example it's sda1.

and enter this command:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

then this command:

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
```

then this command

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

then this command

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

then this command

```
update-grub
```

Comment: Muaad, thanks for these instructions. I discovered the boot partition is sda1 as in the example then entered the second command you gave and nothing appeared to happen. Then I entered your third command and it said:  'mount: mount point /mnt/dev does not exist'

Comment: This is probably beyond my current abilities, but I am wondering if I go ahead and do a full format & install of ubuntu and forget about dual booting, will I still have these boot problems with Ubuntu?

Comment: I'd say that's an overkill Ronan, the question was marked as a duplicate so follow the procedure on already answered questions and good luck.

Comment: I tried the bit in troubleshooting but all that happened is windows appears twice as a boot option! I think I have reached the limit of my abilities and need to find someone who knows Linux to help :) thanks for your advice

Comment: You installed Ubuntu first then you installed Windows, right?

Comment: I edited my answer, take a look at it now and tell me what happens with you, I want to help you Ronnan!

Comment: Reinstalling grub never resolves this problem, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi "TROUBLESHOOTING

YOUR COMPUTER BOOTS DIRECTLY TO WINDOWS

This is a common problem and if you do not get a GRUB menu , re-installing or repairing grub will NOT HELP"

Comment: Hi, thanks Muaad, just taking another look at this now. Sorry for taking days at a time to reply,  and thanks for your help. I installed ubuntu onto a computer that already had windows.

Comment: Muaad, I tried your steps again just now but with the same result, "does not exist"

Comment: bodhi, I followed the troubleshoot instructions but all that happened is that the option to boot from windows now appears twice in the BIOS. I still see no sign of Ubuntu or GRUB in the BIOS and have been through all the menus. Thanks all for your help.