# Only boot direct to windows after Ubuntu install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10, grub-efi

After I installed Ubuntu in a partition on my hard drive, my computer rebooted as normal, but booted straight to windows instead of loading grub. I checked the question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/849839/ubuntu-has-been-installed-but-computer-still-boots-into-windows/849865) and the guide [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi?noredirect=1&lq=1). I've tried all of the suggestions, and at this point I'm stuck. Should I be trying to delete the partition and just start over with the install, with a fresh USB? Or is there something else I should try that isn't outlined in those two forums? Any help would be great.

UPDATE: I've reinstalled Ubuntu in the same partition, with the same result. I disabled secure boot and quick boot this time, but still ran into the same problem.

Comment: With a friend of mine, the Ubuntu loader was hidden as a start-up option like "boot from usb"

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I double-checked that as well, there isn't a boot option for ubuntu. I'm retrying the install now, hopefully that fixes it.

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) from the Ubuntu installation disk started with the "try before installing" option. This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.